# NiFi xml trying to separate a text node that has semi-structured data

Tags: xml, xpath, etl, apache-nifi, processors

Here is sample xml file very simple:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore><book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
  <text>There are several harry potter books: -Chamber of Secrets -Goblet of Fire -</text>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Using NiFi, I would like to

1. rename the text field to `books`
2. Then create a sub-field `book-items`
   with *Chamber of Secrets* as one element and *Goblet of Fire* another element

I am using EvaluateXpath processor to extract the values. I am not sure how to extract out the text field as separate objects

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use the [Apache NiFi RecordPath DSL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html) to manipulate structured data in this way. `RecordPath` allows you to retrieve, modify, and [update fields](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/additionalDetails.html) using a generalized syntax similar to (but not equal to) XPath which applies across all of the various data formats NiFi can interpret as a *record* (CSV, XML, JSON, Avro, etc.).

Comment: Yes, it applies to any of the various data formats NiFi can interpret as a record (CSV, **XML**, JSON, Avro, etc.).

Comment: interesting read but there is no recordpath processor

Comment: Any processor which ends in `*Record` (e.g. `UpdateRecord`, `QueryRecord`, `PartitionRecord`, etc.) can use generic record _readers_ and _writers_ to parse and manipulate record data. [This article](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) is a good introduction.